# how to solve this java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource cannot be cast to org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource?

Tags: java, servlets, jndi, tomcat7

I am trying to do the database connection in tomcat using pooling, this is the what is my context :

```
<Resource name="jdbc/slingemp" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
               username="root" password="root" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
               url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/slingemp"/>
```

and this is what is my web.xml :

```
<description>MySQL JNDI Test</description>
  <resource-ref>
    <description>DB Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/slingemp</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref>
```

and this is how i connect with database :

```
 package org.slingemp.jnditest;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class JNDILookUpServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/JNDILookUpServlet")
public class JNDILookUpServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public JNDILookUpServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            Context initContext = new InitialContext();
            Context envContext  = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
            DataSource ds = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("jdbc/slingemp");
            Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
            if(conn != null)System.out.println("Connected..");
            else System.out.println("Not connected...");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
    }


}
```

but it gives me the following exception :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource cannot be cast to org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource
```

Please help me to resolve this,

Regards

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are just using the wrong import.

replace this:

```
import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource;
```

with this:

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;
```

`javax.sql.DataSource` is the base interface that all `DataSource` implementations must inherit. It is usually not advisable to develop against anything else than this interface.

Answer (score 0):

There are Two options

1. change import

replace

```
import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource;
```

with

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;
```

2. add DataSourceFactory into `Context.xml`

```
factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
```

Answer (score -1):

If you get this error, how to solve this *java.lang.ClassCastException*:

> org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource cannot be cast to
> org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource

Try to replace:

```
import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource;
```

with:

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;
```